# Unknown issue in runtime Perl/Tk

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit

I have tried this code from SU, but it gives this error:

```
couldn't connect to display ":0" at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.30/x86_64-cygwin-threads/Tk/MainWindow.pm line 53.
MainWindow->new() at A2.pl line 9.
```

I'm using Windows 8.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Tk qw{ MainLoop };

my $mw = 'MainWindow'->new;
my $b_show;
$b_show = $mw->Button(-text    => 'Show',
                      -command => sub {
                          $b_show->configure(-command => undef);
                          $mw->Button(-text    => 'Quit',
                                      -command => sub { exit })->pack;
                      })->pack;
MainLoop();
```

Comment: *"I have tried this code from SU ..."* What is SU? How did you install `Tk` on Cygwin?

Comment: @HåkonHægland Probably [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: I’d install a proper Perl on Windows, and not use Cygwin at all. This should work natively, once you have Perl and Tk.pm installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39995584/2173773) answer and according to the [Cygwin/X](https://x.cygwin.com/docs/ug/using.html) documentation, you need to install a Cygwin package called [`xinit`](https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/xinit.html) then open a new Cygwin terminal window and execute the command `startxwin`. Then in another Cygwin terminal, try to rerun your script. This works for me on Windows 11.